# Get column name from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following sample JSON and I would like to get the name of the column like Dribbble, Behance ...

```
{ 
  status: 200,
  success: true,
  result: 
   [ { Dribbble: 'a',
       Behance: '',
       Blog: 'http://blog.invisionapp.com/reimagine-web-design-process/',
       Youtube: '',
       Vimeo: '' },
     { Dribbble: '',
       Behance: '',
       Blog: 'http://creative.mailchimp.com/paint-drips/?_ga=1.32574201.612462484.1431430487',
       Youtube: '',
       Vimeo: '' } ] 
}
```

I'm using Request module and it returns JSON fine but I'm struggling to get the column name in string format. If I could get the column in number format at least, I would be able to know if it's the right column but I get two 0s instead.

```
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        callback(body)
        var json = body.result;

        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var column = Object.keys(key);
                console.log(column[0]); 
            }
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: `Object.keys(json[key])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var json = { 
  "status": 200,
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    { 
        "Dribbble": 'a',
        "Behance": '',
        "Blog": 'http://blog.invisionapp.com/reimagine-web-design-process/',
        "Youtube": '',
        "Vimeo": '' 
    },
    { 
       "Dribbble": '',
       "Behance": '',
       "Blog": 'http://creative.mailchimp.com/paint-drips/?_ga=1.32574201.612462484.1431430487',
       "Youtube": '',
       "Vimeo": '' } 
  ] 
}
// get the results (useful data) somewhere
var results = json["result"];
// get the first result set, or you can loop trhrough all, assuming that each reuslt set is the same. 
if (results.length > 0){ 
  var columnsIn = results[0]; 
  for(var key in columnsIn){
    console.log(key); // here is your column name you are looking for
  } 
}else{
    console.log("No columns");
}
```

This code snippet should point you in the proper direction

Comment: Thanks for showing me the proper example. How is it different from using JSON.parse()?  I'm getting syntax error using that parse method by the way. `var data = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(data.result.Blog);`

Comment: because there is an array, you won't be able to do that, unless you do data.result[0].blog, something along those lines.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to get value of the column? I'm new to this and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Similar to what you were doing to get the key earlier, but you would do something like value = columnsIn[key]

Answer (score 2):

Going off of Chad Peruggia's code, you can print out every key value pair in the results array by doing this:

```
var json = { 
  "status": 200,
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    { 
        "Dribbble": 'a',
        "Behance": '',
        "Blog": 'http://blog.invisionapp.com/reimagine-web-design-process/',
        "Youtube": '',
        "Vimeo": '' 
    },
    { 
       "Dribbble": '',
       "Behance": '',
       "Blog": 'http://creative.mailchimp.com/paint-drips/?_ga=1.32574201.612462484.1431430487',
       "Youtube": '',
       "Vimeo": '' } 
  ] 
}
// get the results (useful data) somewhere
var results = json["result"];
// you can loop through all, assuming that each result set is the same. 
if (results.length > 0) { 
    // iterating through the results array
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        // get i-th object in the results array  
        var columnsIn = results[i];
        // loop through every key in the object
        for(var key in columnsIn){
            console.log(key + ' : ' + results[i][key]); // here is your column name you are looking for + its value
        } 
    }
}
else {
    console.log("No columns");
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! Since Chad was the first and my original question only addressed column name, I will need to choose his answer to be fair.

Comment: That's fine. I was just going to reply to the comment chain, but I didn't have enough reps to do it...